Interact with proxy settings prompt window via ChromeDriver
In my Selenium scenario I have to load some Internet site via proxy. I setup proxy settings in my code and everything works good, but intermittently I get this prompt window in Chrome:

This window then breaks my ChromeDriver work, I can't access any data on the page.
How can I interact with this window and set proxy credentials from my code? Or how can I suppress this window completely?
Currently I setup ChromeDriver this way: (C# example)
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.Proxy = new Proxy
{
    HttpProxy = $"my.proxy.server.address.org:8083",
    SslProxy = $"my.proxy.server.address.org:8083",
    Kind = ProxyKind.Manual,
    IsAutoDetect = false
};
options.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);

var webDriver = new ChromeDriver("c:/chromedriver", options);
NetworkAuthenticationHandler handler = new()
{
    UriMatcher = _ => true,
    Credentials = new PasswordCredentials("proxyUserName", "proxyPassword")
};

var networkInterceptor = webDriver.Manage().Network;
networkInterceptor.ClearAuthenticationHandlers();
networkInterceptor.AddAuthenticationHandler(handler);

Note 1:
Sometimes my Selenium scenario completed successfully, but in ~50% cases I get this proxy credentials prompt.
Note 2:
I tried to access Internet resource via url https://proxyUserName:proxyPassword@site.address.com, but that doesn't help
Appreciate any help!
